# Smarty non-escape characters?

Tags: php, ide, smarty

I have this smarty if statement:

```
{if $webpage.page_heading}
    <h1>{$webpage.page_heading|replace:'\\':'<br />'}</h1>
{/if}`
```

But my IDE is complaining, it looks like this:

[image: Compaining IDE]

Is this just my IDE packing a spaz over the `'\\'` or is there an actual problem here?
I thought that having the double `\` would escape the second backslash?

What we want to do is replace any `\` with a `<br />`

Comment: Why are you doing this in smarty? It is better to replace this in php and pass final variable to smarty...

Comment: Karoly: Yes it works, I am just checking to make sure that something isn't going to break because of it :)

DusanRadojevic: Because this is a cosmetic change, we do different things with the \ depending on where the data is being used, and we use the same variable in multiple places on the same template.

Comment: Why are you using smarty, period? PHP is a templating engine itself, so why add another one top of it? With smarty, you get more overhead and less flexibility.

Comment: because my work uses it in the cms, not an option for me to change it.

Comment: in my experience, smarty creates more compact and readable code (let's be honest, PHP is a horrible templating engine, with virtually no support for all the nice features a templating engine can provide)

Comment: Irrespective of personal opinions of smarty, this question is not relevant to that, perhaps this conversation should be continued in chat? either way, my question remains, am I doing something wrong with the above code, or is it my IDE spazzing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code works, the problem is in your IDE (it probably interprets it as `\'`)